# How do I mount a local folder to a drive letter without SUBST?

Tags: windows, subst

SUBST only mounts local directories to drive letters for the current user, so it often doesn't work (run from scheduled tasks, eleveated privileges etc), and it is not persistent across reboots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locate this key in your registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices
```

and add a String value. Name:

```
P:
```

value (prepend any path with **\??\**):

```
\??\D:\Projects
```

Or, save as .reg file and import:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices]
"P:"="\\??\\D:\\Projects"
```

Source:
https://immo.landwerth.net/2021/07/04/subst/

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4763324).

The idea is to do the mapping under the System account, this way:

- Download [psexec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)
- Open an elevated `cmd.exe` (as administrator)
- Navigate to the folder containing `psexec` and execute the
  following command:

  ```
  psexec -i -s cmd.exe
  ```

  You are now inside of a CMD running under the System account.
- Create the persistent mapped drive as with the following command

  ```
  net use z: \servername\sharedfolder /persistent:yes
  ```

  Note that the newly created mapped drive will now appear for ALL users
  of the computer. They may see it displayed as
  "Disconnected Network Drive (Z:)".
- To get it working after a reboot, see the article
  [Assign Computer Startup Scripts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc770556(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
  to create a script to run on computer startup containing:

  ```
  net use z: \\servername\sharedfolder
  ```

  This will run by default under the System account with no need for `psexec`.

Comment: Interesting tool, psexec.